# Comparing two arrrays

Tags: array, perl

I have two arrays:

- first one is ip addresses from billing for blocking
- second is ip addresses from firewall - already blocked

My task is, compare it, and if ip address new in billing list - block it (run a command) if ip address not in billing list  unblock it.

Current solutions is:

```
#billing->router
foreach $ip (@ipfw_ip) {
    if ( grep $_ eq $ip, @bill_ip ) {
    } else {
        `/sbin/ipfw table 11 add $ip`;
        print "$ip blocked\n";
    }
}

#router->billing
foreach $ip (@bill_ip) {
    if ( grep $_ eq $ip, @ipfw_ip ) {
    } else {
        `/sbin/ipfw table 11 delete $ip`;
        print "$ip unblocked\n";
    }
}
```

I hate 'grep' in the loops, and looking for better solution. Any advice?

UPD: 
difference function from Set::Functional helps me.

```
for(difference (\@ipfw_ip, \@bill_ip)) {
     ..._;
}
sub difference(@) {
    my $first = shift;

    return unless $first && @$first;

    my %set;

    undef @set{@$first};

    do { delete @set{@$_} if @$_ } for @_;

    return keys %set;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Set::Functional` to make the code very short:

```
use Set::Functional 'difference';
for(difference [@ipfw_ip], [@bill_ip]) {
    `/sbin/ipfw table 11 add $ip`;
    print "$ip blocked\n";
}
```

Another advantage of the approach above is that you don't have to worry about duplicate entries in the two arrays.

Comment: Thank you alot! I dislike new dependencies but looks into Set::Functional and see the code. Its simple. I will update my question with solution.

Answer (score 1):

The completely procedural way to write the same is:

```
foreach my $fw_ip (@ipfw_ip) {
    foreach my $bill_ip (@bill_ip) {
       if($fw_ip eq $bill_ip) {
           ...
           last;
       }
    }
}
```

The main advantage is that it is easy to understand for anybody, and not using too much perl-fu.

I find it odd that you write

```
    if ( grep $_ eq $ip, @bill_ip ) {
    } else {
        `/sbin/ipfw table 11 add $ip`;
        print "$ip blocked\n";
    }
```

In stead of

```
    if ( not grep $_ eq $ip, @bill_ip ) {
        `/sbin/ipfw table 11 add $ip`;
        print "$ip blocked\n";
    }
```

or even

```
    unless ( grep $_ eq $ip, @bill_ip ) {
        `/sbin/ipfw table 11 add $ip`;
        print "$ip blocked\n";
    }
```

P.s. *always* `use strict;` and `use warnings;`. It looks as if you aren't.

Comment: 2xforeach the same then grep in foreach. I hope it possible do that task without loop in loop. And thank you about "if else" no idea how I writed that. Probably there was deleted code.

Comment: Sure - you can do the same completely without a loop. Will be back with that.